# Replace double br with paragraphs in PHP with Regex

Tags: php, regex, nl2br

I have the following text (string from SQL):

```
Paragraph \n Newline \n\n Paragraph2 \n\n\n\n Paragraph3
```

This line is processed by:

```
function nl2brAndParagraphs($text) {
    $br = nl2br($text);
    $data = preg_replace('/^\s*(?:<br\s*\/?>\s*)*/i', '', $br); //Remove any whitespace and br- tags that are at the beginning of the text
$data = preg_replace('/\s*(?:<br\s*\/?>\s*)*$/i', '', $data); //Remove any whitespace and br- tags that are at the end of the text

$data = preg_replace('#(?:<br\s*/?>\s*?){2,}#','</p>
    <p>',$data); //Replace multiple line breaks with paragraphs
$data = '<p>'.$data.'</p>';
return $data;
}
```

This should return:

```
<p>Paragraph <br /> Newline </p><p> Paragraph2 </p><p> Paragraph3</p>
```

but returns

```
<p>paragraph1 <br /> Newline </p><p> paragraph2 </p><p></p><p> paragraph3</p>
```

How do I fix the `</p><p></p><p>` part, where there only should be `</p><p>`?

Comment: Where do the `pre` and `code` tags come from? What's returned in `$data`?

Comment: @CarstenHagemann Updated question. -I was using the wrong method to see the content of $data before. Now I know the pre-tag problem is caused by markdown when used with nl2brAndParagraphs. nl2brAndParagraphs still returns too many paragraph- tags between paragraphs 2 and 3 though

Comment: You should open a new question regarding the markdown-filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This removes any empty paragraphs:

```
$data = preg_replace('/<p[^>]*>\s*?<\/p[^>]*>/', '', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

This consolidates multiple consecutive paragraph tags into one:

```
$data = preg_replace('# (\s*<\/p>\s*<p>){2,}#',' <\/p><p>',$data);
```

[Demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/nK8uH0/1)

Comment: This seems to be working on the demo at regex101, but results in `Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '{' ` when running it on my page?

Comment: I added the delimiters (http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php).

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me (Regex noob here, sorry). `$data = preg_replace('# (\s*<\/p>\s*<p>){2,}#',' <\/p><p>',$data);` doesn't seem to affect the string. -$data is still `<p>paragraf<br />
br</p>
        <p>
paragraf2</p>
        <p>
</p>
        <p>
paragraf3</p>` Tried # (\s*<\/p>\s*<p>){2,}#g`but that produces a `warning: unknown modifier 'g'` Also tried replacing # with /